# OnClick method in Fragment using Scenes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception, onclick

when I've fragment as a rootContainer for 2 scenes.
First scene1 is displayed. When user select particular option, app's going to 2nd scene.
Scene2 is copy of scene1 but with few modifications, new TextView and Button.

When user clicks the button, I wish app returned to previous layout.
I've written method:

```
public void exit(View v) {scene2.exit();}
```

and passed it's name as an argument in OnClick property for button.

Unfortunately I can't switch to previous layout. System throws following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method exit(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'button'
```

Fragment's java code

```
    public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {


    private ViewGroup rootContainer;
    private Scene scene1, scene2;
    private Transition transitionMgr;
    private SecondViewModel mViewModel;
    private TextView valueView, rateView;

    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
        return new SecondFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_container_fragment, container, false);

        transitionMgr = TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.transition);
        rootContainer = (ViewGroup) v;
        scene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootContainer, R.layout.scene2, getActivity());
        scene1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootContainer, R.layout.scene1, getActivity());
        scene1.enter();


        return v;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SecondViewModel.class);
        mViewModel.getValueObject().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), valueObserver);
        valueView = rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.valueView);


    }


 [....]

[....]
   

[.....]

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.one:
                layoutPrepare("Dollar");
                return true;
            case R.id.two:
                layoutPrepare("Euro");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void layoutPrepare(String currency) {
        scene2.setEnterAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setHasOptionsMenu(false);
                rateView = rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.rateView);
                rateView.setText(String.valueOf(mViewModel.getRate(currency)));
                valueView = rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.valueView);
                valueView.setText(String.valueOf(mViewModel.conversion(currency)));

            }
        });

        TransitionManager.go(scene2, transitionMgr);
    }


public void exit(View v)
{
    scene2.exit();
}
}
```

XML's for scene1 and scene2:

scene1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valueView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

scene2:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valueView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="464dp"
        android:text="test"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rateView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:text="test"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="exit"
        android:text="Return"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.89" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would solve your problem,
but judging on definition of **tools:context**

> The tools: context has a primary role in defining which Activity or Fragment class has instantiated the layout which is being defined.

Both of your XMLs have tools: context pointing to SecondFragment.

So please try changing the layout to pointing to their corresponding fragments.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The SecondFragment is kind of rootContainer for all those scenes. It's place of where corresponding layouts are loading.  Scene1 and scene2  has the same contex class because they aren't separate fragments.

Comment: Yeah understood that, but in this article : https://blog.mindorks.com/what-is-tools-context-in-android-layout-files found that "Apart from this, the tools:context is used for rendering the action bar or it can be used to find the correct place to insert the onClick handlers when you want to perform some click operations." So was wondering if changing that, solved your problem.